# Populate column with generated series

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-update

Having accidentally deleted information from an auto-incrementing primary key id column in Postgres, my goal is to re-populate it with a generated series of data.  For example:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET id = (SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(1,3456))
```

This throws the error:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

```
UPDATE mytable
SET id = SELECT a.n from generate_series(1, 3456) as a(n)
```

(throws a syntax error)

What is the correct method to update a single column with a generated series in PostgreSQL?  Why does `SET` not work here?

Comment: The error comes from `generate_series` returning many rows - so you're essentially trying to set the ID of every row in mytable to the multiple rows returned by `generate_series`.

Comment: To literally answer your question about syntax, you need to treat the `generate_series()` as a table, not as a value.  *(Note, this doesn't do what you want, it just avoids the syntax error)*  `UPDATE mytable SET id = a.n FROM generate_series(1, 3456) AS a(n)`.  The reason that this doesn't do what you want it that there's then still an implicit cartesian product, which a `WHERE` clause would normally avoid; `UPDATE mytable SET id = a.n FROM generate_series(1, 3456) AS a(n) WHERE mytable.something = a.something`, unfortunately you have nothing you ***can*** point in that `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a primary key, you can do:

```
UPDATE mytable t
    SET id = new_id
    FROM (SELECT tt.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as new_id
          FROM mytable tt
         ) tt
    WHERE t.id = tt.id;
```

Comment: This may not work as the OP seemed to indicate that they deleted the ID

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the id column of some rows, want to give them an ID again and don't care what the ID is you could use something like:

```sql
UPDATE mytable 
SET id = nextval('mytable_id_seq')
WHERE id IS NULL
```